# Menu em PHP e HTML

Tags: php, html, menu, include

Preciso que tirem uma dúvida pra mim, criei uma página e coloquei o menu em PHP. Segue dados:

menu.php

```
<div class="col-md-9 text-left float-left collapse-navation">
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse navbar-inverse no-transition">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
            <li><a href="../index.html">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="../#sobre">Sobre</a></li>
            <li><a href="../#work">Destaques</a></li>
            <li><a href="../#titulos">Títulos</a></li>
            <li><a href="../#testimonial">Testemunho</a></li>
            <li class="last"><a href="../#contato">Contato</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

E coloquei em outra página o include.php:

```
<?php
include ('../menu.php');
?>
```

Porém quando o menu entra na página os links criados não funcionam quando clica em cima deles, só funcionando se clicar com o botão direito e abrir em nova aba. O que pode ser? O problema é somente esse, os links.

Meu servidor é da Locaweb.

Comment: Vejo que você está usando urls relativas, veja se o arquivo onde você está setando o include realmente se encontra um nivel abaixo do arquivo menu.php.

Comment: Olá Diego, está sim; tanto que quando clico com o botão direito e abrir em nova aba ele abre corretamente. Minha dúvida é se o código está correto, ou se poderia ser do servidor, no caso Locaweb; ou se preciso verificar se está dando conflito com algum javascrip da página.

Comment: Outra coisa, pra que aquele  "#" antes dos links? você está usando âncoras?

Comment: O site é uma OnePage, criei um ID com os nomes, usa o # pra ir onde onde se inicia o trecho dessa onepage, seria: index.html#contato; ao clicar nisso vai pra parte contato dessa onepage

Comment: Na verdade, ancoras você referencia usando o "name" na tag de link. Troque para <a name="sobre"></a> e faça o teste.

Comment: tenho quase certeza que seu problema esta relacionado com javascript... seria bom colocar o codigo do javascript também

Comment: Se voce esta usando estes `#` para ir a outro canto da Onpage eu não entendi qual a duvida em relação a `PHP`...

Comment: Bom consegui! Respondendo aos comentarios: Diego, fiz e deu certo nesse caso tbm... o problema era um js identifiquei e vou corrigir. Rafael esse página que estou criando é uma nova, não faz parte da onepage. Valeu galera pela ajuda! Deu certo agora.

Comment: `collapse-navation` ? O nome da classe no bootstrap não seria `collapse-navigation` ?

Answer (score 1):

Esse tipo de links só funcionará na própria página, ou então com a execução de javascript.

Da forma que esta o código, verifico que está a retornar a outra.

Answer (score 0):

Quando você faz uso de `#ocorrencia` na URL, significa que você está apontando para um lugar ancorado da sua página.

Ele vai percorrer até encontrar a ocorrência na mesma página `<a name="ocorrencia" id="ocorrencia"></a>`, e neste caso não faz nenhum sentido você colocar **"../"** mapeamento do endereço antes disso, pois será ignorado pela âncora, pois quando clicar não vai mudar a sua página, nem com "reza brava". Um exemplo de uso de link por cerquilha (#) que mudaria a página é através de criação de rotas usando Angular JS, mas daí já entra tecnologia ajax no meio, o que não tem muito a ver com o que você está com dúvida, aparentemente.